# jqGrid celledit under certain conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want the cells to be in edit mode when a certain condition is true. I'm using cellEdit true and editable in the column but in some occasions the user shouldn't be able to edit some cells of the same column even though the column is editable=true. I need to use cell editing not inline editing.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a `beforeEditCell` event that you can handle; enough information is passed in about the cell to be edited that you should be able to determine if you want that cell to be editable.  However, what I don't know is whether you can stop editing from happening within your event handler.  You might try returning `false` from that event handler for those cells you don't want to be editable.